# looking for php url rewrite class or scheme

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I need to use an url rewrite scheme but i would like to be able to add my var without changing .htaccess rules

i was thinking about a scheme mostly like the one used by CodeIgniter
can't find any PHP class or other scheme articles

Comment: it could be but i was wondering if somebody wrote a class to parse url into array and viceversa AND if may be does exist a different way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Try to write in .htaccess redirect from any url to index.php, then in index.php you can get requested URL with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and handle it.
So if you want, you can save your pages data in database, then get it from index.php and handle request withem... and so on...